# Statement won't print

Tags: python

Statement prints when the corrected answer is given, but won't print when it's given the wrong answer.

```
QUESTIONS = ["2 + 2", "10 // 5", "8 == 2 ** 3", "5 % 2 == 0"]
ANSWERS = ["4", "2", "True", "False"]


def main():
    count=0
    question=0
    for i in QUESTIONS:
        print(i)
        z=input("enter your answer:")
        for x in range(len(QUESTIONS)):
            if z == ANSWERS[x]:
                print("Your answer is correct. Good job!")
                count=count+1
                question=question+1
                if z!=ANSWERS[x]:
                    print("Your answer is wrong")
                    question = question+1
        if z == "quit":
            break  
    print("You have"+ " "+ str(count) + " " + "points.") 
    print(("You have answered " + str(question)) + " " + "correctly out of 4.") 
main()
```

How can I get it to print the statement when an incorrect answer is given. Also How can I add the percentage at the end to tell me how many % I got correct ( ratio of correct answers ) .
 [image]

Comment: `if z!=ANSWERS[x]:` - this will never be satisfied because you're checking it inside a block with the opposite condition. Try unindenting it to be level with the `if z == ANSWERS[x]:` (and you can just replace it with an `else:` too)

Comment: It printed, but it printed 4 times

Comment: oh yes, I see why it would do that. Try to think about why that is and what logic you can use to only print it once. I'm assuming you're a beginner, figuring this out (it really isn't hard) is a good exercise for how to work through the logic of making code work.

Comment: I believe its something with the range but I'm not sure how to implement a solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major problems with your code that I can see:

1.) Your code will print "Your answer is correct. Good job!" if I enter any of the possible answers, regardless of what the current question is. For example, if the question is "2 + 2" and I enter "2", your code will say that this answer is correct. This is due to your `for x in range(len(QUESTIONS))` loop. It compares the user's input with all answers, and if any one of them matches it's happy.

2.) The code that prints "Your answer is wrong" cannot ever be reached and will never be executed. This is due to the fact that you've nested one if-statement in another.

```
def main():
    questions = [
        "What is 2 + 2?",
        "What is 10 // 5?",
        "True or False: 8 == 2 ** 3",
        "True or False: 5 % 2 == 0"
    ]

    answers = [
        "4",
        "2",
        "True",
        "False"
    ]

    correctly_answered_count = 0

    for current_question, current_answer in zip(questions, answers):
        print(current_question)
        user_answer = input("Enter your answer: ")
        if user_answer == current_answer:
            print("Your answer is correct. Good job!")
            correctly_answered_count += 1
        else:
            print("Your answer is wrong.")
    print(f"You have answered {correctly_answered_count} correctly out of {len(questions)}.")

main()
```

Output:

```
What is 2 + 2?
Enter your answer: 2
Your answer is wrong.
What is 10 // 5?
Enter your answer: 2
Your answer is correct. Good job!
True or False: 8 == 2 ** 3
Enter your answer: True
Your answer is correct. Good job!
True or False: 5 % 2 == 0
Enter your answer: False
Your answer is correct. Good job!
You have answered 3 correctly out of 4.
```